# Basis Pursuit Denoising (BPDN) algorithm for Direction of Arrival Estimation

Tags: discrete-signals, beamforming, array-signal-processing, doa, space-communications

I am working on Compressive sensing algorithms for DOA estimation. Can i get any references for writing BPDN code in MATLAB.

Comment: Don't really now anything about the topic of Compressive Sensing but a quick Google search showed up this MATLAB function (https://www.mathworks.com/help/wavelet/ref/sensingdictionary.basispursuit.html) which can serve as a starting point for your work.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [SPGL1](https://friedlander.io/spgl1/). It's probably the one most often used for basis pursuit/compressive sensing.